# Mapping columns/rows from one dataframe to another based on row number

Tags: r, indexing, rows

I have two dataframes:

```
df1<-structure(list(Name = c("sub7", "sub7", "sub7", "sub7", "sub7", 
              "sub7", "sub7", "sub7", "sub7", "sub7"), StimulusName = c("Alpha1", 
               "Alpha1", "Alpha1", "Alpha1", "Alpha1", "Alpha1", "Alpha1", "Alpha1", 
                "Alpha1", "Alpha1"), PupilLeft = c(10.046, 10.05, 10.062, 10.072, 
                10.072, 10.056, 10.056, 10.056, 10.066, 10.066)), row.names = c(NA, 
                -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



    df2<-structure(list(Name = c("sub7", "sub7"), StimulusName = c("Alpha1", 
              "Alpha1"), Row_Num = c(1, 3), Label = c("Onset", "Offset")), row.names = c(NA, 
                -2L), vars = "Name", drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:1), group_sizes = 2L, biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
               Name = "Guilty Subject 07"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Name", drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
               "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'd like to take the values from the columns `Row_Num` and `Label` in `df2` and map them to rows in `df1` corresponding to the numbers in `Row_Num`.

I would like to achieve this without using loops. Perhaps just using the `Row_Num` values as an index?

The final dataframe in this instance would look like:

```
     Name  StimulusName PupilLeft Row_Num Label 
 1   sub7  Alpha1            10.0       1 Onset 
 2   sub7  Alpha1            10.0      NA NA    
 3   sub7  Alpha1            10.1       3 Offset
 4   sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA NA    
 5   sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA NA    
 6   sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA NA    
 7   sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA NA    
 8   sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA NA    
 9   sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA NA    
10   sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA NA
```

Comment: Are you also joining by `Name` and `StimulusName`, not `Row_Num` alone?

Comment: No, I'm just interested in matching the values in 'Row_Num' to the corresponding row numbers in df1. I don't mind if 'Name' and 'StimulusName' are carried over, but it's not a requisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Row_Num = row_number()) %>%
   left_join(df2) %>%
   mutate(Row_Num = replace(Row_Num, !Row_Num %in% c(1, 3), NA))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#   Name  StimulusName PupilLeft Row_Num Label 
#   <chr> <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 sub7  Alpha1            10.0       1 Onset 
# 2 sub7  Alpha1            10.0      NA <NA>  
# 3 sub7  Alpha1            10.1       3 Offset
# 4 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 5 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 6 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 7 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 8 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 9 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
#10 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>
```

---

If it is to join by row names

```
rownames_to_column(df1, "Row_Num") %>% 
    mutate(Row_Num = as.numeric(Row_Num)) %>% 
    left_join(., df2 %>% 
                   ungroup %>% 
                   select(Row_Num, Label), by = "Row_Num") %>%
    mutate(Row_Num = replace(Row_Num, !Row_Num %in% c(1, 3), NA))
```

---

Or using `match` from `base R`

```
i1 <- match(row.names(df1), df2$Row_Num)
df1[names(df2)[3:4]] <- lapply(df2[3:4], `[`, i1)
df1
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#   Name  StimulusName PupilLeft Row_Num Label 
#   <chr> <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 sub7  Alpha1            10.0       1 Onset 
# 2 sub7  Alpha1            10.0      NA <NA>  
# 3 sub7  Alpha1            10.1       3 Offset
# 4 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 5 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 6 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 7 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 8 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
# 9 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>  
#10 sub7  Alpha1            10.1      NA <NA>
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks for the response. Does this solution rely on manually inputting the row numbers into the dplyr chain?

Comment: @Docconcoct  Unfortunately, we have to create a column because if you look at the two datasets, the 'Name' and 'StimulusName' that is common in both columns are duplicated.  If we join by these columns, it results in duplication of rows as it is non-specific join

Comment: @akrun Maybe I read it wrong, but it looked like OP just wanted to join by row number. Not `Name` and `StimulusName`. So we would have columns like `Name.y` and `StimulusName.y`.

Comment: @Docconcoct  You can check the `match` based approach.  It may be the one based on the logic you commented

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create `Row_Num` in `df1` before you merge.

```
df_out <- merge(
      transform(df1, Row_Num = seq_len(nrow(df1))),
      df2,
      by = c("Name", "StimulusName", "Row_Num"),
      all.x = TRUE)
df_out$Row_Num <- ifelse(df_out$Row_Num %in% df2$Row_Num, df_out$Row_Num, NA)
df_out
#   Name StimulusName Row_Num PupilLeft  Label
#1  sub7       Alpha1       1    10.046  Onset
#2  sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.050   <NA>
#3  sub7       Alpha1       3    10.062 Offset
#4  sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.072   <NA>
#5  sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.072   <NA>
#6  sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.056   <NA>
#7  sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.056   <NA>
#8  sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.056   <NA>
#9  sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.066   <NA>
#10 sub7       Alpha1      NA    10.066   <NA>
```

Comment: I like this idea as a simple solution, however, I'm keen to only have the values in 'Row_Num' in df2 appear in the new column 'Row_Num' in df1. This is for visual inspection/confirmation reasons. Thanks.

Comment: This joins by `StimulusName` and `Name` which OP does not want. For example, this would have problems if df2 had "Alpha2" as a value in `StimulusName`.

Comment: I see OP's comment now. When I answer I looked at his expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If we are only joining by `Row_Num` then we could do:

```
rownames(df2) <- df2$Row_Num
merge(df1, df2, by=0, all.x=TRUE)

   Row.names Name.x StimulusName.x PupilLeft Name.y StimulusName.y Row_Num  Label
1          1   sub7         Alpha1    10.046   sub7         Alpha1       1  Onset
2         10   sub7         Alpha1    10.066   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
3          2   sub7         Alpha1    10.050   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
4          3   sub7         Alpha1    10.062   sub7         Alpha1       3 Offset
5          4   sub7         Alpha1    10.072   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
6          5   sub7         Alpha1    10.072   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
7          6   sub7         Alpha1    10.056   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
8          7   sub7         Alpha1    10.056   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
9          8   sub7         Alpha1    10.056   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
10         9   sub7         Alpha1    10.066   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
```

Alternatively, you might want to use:

```
merge(df1, df2, by="row.names", all.x=TRUE)
```

To make the by argument a little less cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

How about `merge`?

```
df2 <- data.frame(df2, stringsAsFactors = F)
df3 <- merge(df1,df2)
> df3
   Name StimulusName PupilLeft Row_Num  Label
1  sub7       Alpha1    10.046       1  Onset
2  sub7       Alpha1    10.046       3 Offset
3  sub7       Alpha1    10.050       1  Onset
4  sub7       Alpha1    10.050       3 Offset
5  sub7       Alpha1    10.062       1  Onset
6  sub7       Alpha1    10.062       3 Offset
7  sub7       Alpha1    10.072       1  Onset
8  sub7       Alpha1    10.072       3 Offset
9  sub7       Alpha1    10.072       1  Onset
10 sub7       Alpha1    10.072       3 Offset
11 sub7       Alpha1    10.056       1  Onset
12 sub7       Alpha1    10.056       3 Offset
13 sub7       Alpha1    10.056       1  Onset
14 sub7       Alpha1    10.056       3 Offset
15 sub7       Alpha1    10.056       1  Onset
16 sub7       Alpha1    10.056       3 Offset
17 sub7       Alpha1    10.066       1  Onset
18 sub7       Alpha1    10.066       3 Offset
19 sub7       Alpha1    10.066       1  Onset
20 sub7       Alpha1    10.066       3 Offset
```

EDIT: using your proposed method with rownames as index:

```
df1$id <- 1:nrow(df1)
df2$id <- 1:nrow(df2)
df4 <- merge(df1,df2, by="id", all.x=T)
> df4
   id Name.x StimulusName.x PupilLeft Name.y StimulusName.y Row_Num  Label
1   1   sub7         Alpha1    10.046   sub7         Alpha1       1  Onset
2   2   sub7         Alpha1    10.050   sub7         Alpha1       3 Offset
3   3   sub7         Alpha1    10.062   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
4   4   sub7         Alpha1    10.072   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
5   5   sub7         Alpha1    10.072   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
6   6   sub7         Alpha1    10.056   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
7   7   sub7         Alpha1    10.056   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
8   8   sub7         Alpha1    10.056   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
9   9   sub7         Alpha1    10.066   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
10 10   sub7         Alpha1    10.066   <NA>           <NA>      NA   <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to consider my request @gpier. However, I'd like the number values in the column 'Row_Num' in df2 to be used to map to the corresponding rows in df1. See my example finished dataframe that differs from yours.